# apply regression while looping through levels of a factor in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a regression function to each separate level of a factor (Subject). The idea is that for each Subject, I can get a predicted reading time based on their actual reading time(RT) and the length of the corresponding printed string (WordLen). I was helped along by a colleague with some code for applying the function based on each level of another function (Region) within (Subject). However, neither the original code nor my attempted modification (to applying the function across breaks by a single factor) works.

Here is an attempt at some sample data:

```
 test0<-structure(list(Subject = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
103L, 103L), Region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), RT = c(294L, 241L, 346L, 339L, 332L, NA, 399L, 
377L, 400L, 439L, 905L, 819L, 600L, 520L, 811L, 1021L, 508L, 
550L, 1048L, 1246L, 470L, NA, 385L, 347L, 592L, 507L, 472L, 396L, 
761L, 430L), WordLen = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Region", "RT", "WordLen"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

The unfortunate thing is that this data is returning a problem that I don't get with my full dataset:

```
"Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases"
```

Maybe this is because the sample data is too small?

Anyway, I am hoping that someone will see the issue with the code, despite my ability to provide working data...

This is the original code (does not work):

```
for(i in 1:length(levels(test0$Subject)))
  for(j in 1:length(levels(test0$Region)))
    {tmp=predict(lm(RT~WordLen,test0[test0$Subject==levels(test0$Subject)[i] & test0$Region==levels(test0$Region)[j],],na.action="na.exclude"))
    test0[names(tmp),"rt.predicted"]=tmp
    }
```

And this is the modified code (which not surprisingly, also does not work):

```
for(i in 1:length(levels(test0$Subject)))
    {tmp=predict(lm(RT~WordLen,test0[test0$Subject==levels(test0$Subject)[i],],na.action="na.exclude"))
    test0[names(tmp),"rt.predicted"]=tmp
    }
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: also see `?lmList` in the `nlme` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve result with function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. 
This will split data frame according to `Subject`, calculate prediction of regression model and then add as new column to data frame.

```
ddply(test0,.(Subject),transform, 
   pred=predict(lm(RT~WordLen,na.action="na.exclude")))

   Subject Region   RT WordLen     pred
1      101      1  294       3 327.9778
......
4      101      1  339       3 327.9778
5      101      1  332       3 327.9778
6      101      2   NA       3       NA
7      101      2  399       5 363.8444
.......
13     102      1  600       3 785.4146
```

To split data by `Subject` and `Region` you should put both variable inside `.()`.

```
ddply(test0,.(Subject,Region),transform,
    pred=predict(lm(RT~WordLen,na.action="na.exclude")))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. How would I modify this to also break by Region (perform the regression on each Region of each Subject)?

Comment: Excellent. I'm still curious as to why the original loop method did not work. I realize loops should not be my first line of attack with R, but it would be good to know.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem in your test data is that `Subject` and `Region` are not factors.

```
test0$Subject <- factor(test0$Subject)
test0$Region <- factor(test0$Region)

for(i in 1:length(levels(test0$Subject)))
  for(j in 1:length(levels(test0$Region)))
  {tmp=predict(lm(RT~WordLen,test0[test0$Subject==levels(test0$Subject)[i] & test0$Region==levels(test0$Region)[j],],na.action="na.exclude"))
   test0[names(tmp),"rt.predicted"]=tmp
  }
#   26     27     28     29     30 
# 442.25 442.25 560.50 678.75 442.25
```

The reason you were getting the error you were (`0 non-NA cases`) is that when you were subsetting, you were doing it on levels of variables that were not factors. In you original dataset, try:

```
test0[test0$Subject==levels(test0$Subject)[1],]
```

You get:

```
# [1] Subject Region  RT      WordLen
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Which is what `lm()` was trying to work with

Comment: Thank you for catching this mistake. In my original data they are factors, but I missed this when cutting down the data.

Answer (score 2):

While your questions seems to be asking for explanation of error, which others have answered (data not being factor at all), here is a way to do it using just `base` packages

```
test0$rt.predicted <- unlist(by(test0[, c("RT", "WordLen")], list(test0$Subject, test0$Region), FUN = function(x) predict(lm(RT ~ 
    WordLen, x, na.action = "na.exclude"))))

test0
##    Subject Region   RT WordLen rt.predicted
## 1      101      1  294       3     310.4000
## 2      101      1  241       3     310.4000
## 3      101      1  346       3     310.4000
## 4      101      1  339       3     310.4000
## 5      101      1  332       3     310.4000
## 6      101      2   NA       3     731.0000
## 7      101      2  399       5     731.0000
## 8      101      2  377       7     731.0000
## 9      101      2  400       3     731.0000
## 10     101      2  439       9     731.0000
## 11     102      1  905       3     448.5000
## 12     102      1  819       3           NA
## 13     102      1  600       3     448.5000
## 14     102      1  520       3     448.5000
## 15     102      1  811       3     448.5000
## 16     102      2 1021       3           NA
## 17     102      2  508       3     399.0000
## 18     102      2  550       5     408.5000
## 19     102      2 1048       7     389.5000
## 20     102      2 1246       3     418.0000
## 21     103      1  470       3     870.4375
## 22     103      1   NA       3     870.4375
## 23     103      1  385       3     877.3750
## 24     103      1  347       3     884.3125
## 25     103      1  592       3     870.4375
## 26     103      2  507       3     442.2500
## 27     103      2  472       3     442.2500
## 28     103      2  396       5     560.5000
## 29     103      2  761       7     678.7500
## 30     103      2  430       3     442.2500
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternate - . The factor level issue was only secondary. The real issue was that my code did not work with the real data set (which had the factor levels correctly encoded). Or am I wrong, and are you saying that my original code should have worked???

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that this is caused by the fact that for a combination of your two categorical variables no data exists. What you could do is to first extract the subset, check if it isn't equal to `NULL`, and only perform the lm if there is data.